Phanton wallet on Android keeps crashing/closing
I cant get my Phantom Wallet started on my Android mobile. It keeps crashing/forced closing. Sometimes, there is the message that the app gets terminated repeatedly, sometimes there is not message at all.
It is a rather old phone with Android 9.0
Phanton wallet app version is latest for me (24.26.0)

Anyone? I could also install an older version if that helps (and you can provide me with the corresponding Aurora store version code).

The Solana Stack Exchange isn't Phantom support unfortunately! You'll have to ask their support team directly
